# Python - How to make two very similar code blocks one/shorter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to reuse a function, for example, to shorten the code below?

```py
x, y, m = 3, 5, 10

if x == 0:
    pass  # code block 1
elif x == m:
    pass  # code block 2
else:
    pass  # code block 1
    pass  # code block 2

if y == 0:
    pass  # code block 3
elif y == m:
    pass  # code block 4
else:
    pass  # code block 3
    pass  # code block 4
```

EDIT: A non-working example could look like this:

```py
def func(var, code_1, code_2):
    if var != m:
        code_1
    if var != 0:
        code_2


func(x, code_block_1, code_block_2)
func(y, code_block_3, code_block_4)
```

EDIT2: I saw someone (Ottomated) on YouTube/Twitch using something I thought of but not in Python. Is is possible to have a similar structure in Python?
The code blocks are obviously very different but the idea of inserting a variable or function name is similar.

[OttomatedInterfaceFunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzY6Y.jpg)
(sorry for the bad image quality)

Comment: Since this is working code you want to improve, it is perhaps a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where you can get advice on ways to improve it, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules.

Comment: In short, yes, you can define functions & call them instead of duplicating blocks of code (that's one of the key advantages to using functions). You may also be able to improve the logic used for the conditionals to further refactor the code. Aside: please, don't use `max` as a variable name, its a builtin function already.

Answer (score 2):

I might write this like:

```
x, y, m = 3, 5, 10

if x != m:
    pass  # code block 1
if x != 0:
    pass  # code block 2

if y != m:
    pass  # code block 3
if y != 0:
    pass  # code block 4
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can try something like this:

```
x_val = {value: code1_as_string, value2: code2_as_string}
y_val = {value: code1_as_string, value2: code2_as_string}

exec(x_val[x])
exec(y_val[y])
```

but i don't thing that will be the optimal / clearest way, i think it will be better to do it in the common way with if else for every case